# read a scala conf file from a maven jar

Tags: scala, maven, jar

I would like to read two scala conf file from a maven jar named myconfiguration1.conf and myconfiguration2.conf:

```
driver= oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
user = myUser
password = pass
url = myUrl
table = my_table
```

before generate my jar, i used a line like this:

```
val myconfig1 = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("./my-project/src/main/resources/myconfiguration1.conf")) 
val myconfig2 = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("./my-project/src/main/resources/myconfiguration2.conf"))
```

Inside my jar, i have a tree like this

```
my-project-0.0.1.jar
      |___ myconfiguration1.conf
      |___ myconfiguration2.conf
```

Do you have any idea since the two lines don't work with the jar file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you are using **typesafe config** to load the **conf** file, you can directly use `ConfigFactory.load("myconfiguration1.conf")` and `ConfigFactory.load("myconfiguration2.conf")` to load the **classpath** configuration file.

[public static load(java.lang.String resourceBasename)](https://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/index.html)

Comment: I was to rapid, it doesn't work since myconfiguration1.conf is a file that i personnaly edit. so I don't want classpath configuration. I just want to acces my personnal conf file in order to parse it from my jar

Comment: Hi @a.moussa, when you run your jar, you can add the **specify folder** in **classpath**, so it's still can read properties like this way and also you can edit this file. maybe this is helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857705/add-properties-file-on-classpath